# How does a Node.js server (like Express) manage memory as opposed to a PHP server?

Tags: php, node.js, express, yii

From what I understand, basically, PHP server-side apps (PHP-FPM) load the entire app from scratch on every request and then close it down at the end of a request. Meaning that variables, containers, config and everything else gets read and built from zero in each separate request and there is no crossover. I can use this knowledge to structure the app better. For example, I would know that class statics hold their data only for the duration of the request and each new request will have its own value.

A Node.js server like Express.js works very differently, however. It is a single Node.js process that is running continually and listens for any new requests and passes them along to the correct handlers. This requires a different approach to development, as there is data that is kept in memory between requests. For example, class statics in such a case sound like they would hold data for the entire duration of the server uptime, not just for the duration of a single request.

So I have some questions about this:

1. Does it make sense to pre-load some data during Express.js startup (like reading private keys from file) so that it is already in memory when needed by a request and it would get re-used each time without being re-read from file? In a PHP server framework this wouldn't matter that much as everything gets built from 0 with each request.
2. How do I properly handle exceptions in a Node.js server process? If a PHP server script throws a fatal exception only that specific request dies, all other requests and any new ones run fine. If a fatal error happens in a Node.js server, it sounds like it would kill the entire process and thus all requests with it.

If you have any resources about how this topic, it'd be great if you could share them also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1-

> Does it make sense to pre-load some data during Express.js startup (like reading private keys from file) so that it is already in memory when needed by a request and it would get re-used each time without being re-read from file? In a PHP server framework this wouldn't matter that much as everything gets built from 0 with each request.

Yes, totally. You would bootstrap connections to databases, data read for files and similar tasks at application startup, so they are always available in every request.

There are some things to consider in this scenario:

- During application startup, you can safely call synchronous methods, like `fs.readFileSync` etc, because there are not concurrent request on the single thread at this point.
- CommonJS modules does cache their first value exported. So if you choose to use a dedicate module to handle secrets read from a file, database connections etc., you can:

**secrets.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const gmailSecretApiKey = fs.readFileSync('path_to_file');
const mailgunSecretApiKey = fs.readFileSync('path_to_file'); 
...

module.exports = {
gmailSecretApiKey,
mailgunSecretApiKey,
...
}
```

Then `require` this as your application startup. After this, any modules that does:
`const gmailKey = require('.../secrets').gmailSecretApiKey` **won't** read from file again. The results are cached in the module.

This is important because allow you to use `require` and `import` for consuming configuration in your controllers and modules, without bothering passing extra parameters to your http controllers or adding them to `req` objects.

- Depending upon infrastructure, you may not be able to allow your application to not handling requests during startup (i.e. you have only one machine up and don't want to give `service unavailble` to your clients). In such cases, you can expose all the configuration and shared resources in promises, and bootstrap your web controllers **as fast as possible**,  waiting for the promises inside. Let's say we need kafka up and running when handling a request on '/user':

**kafka.js**

```
function kafka() {
    // return some promise of an object that can publish and read from kafka in a given port etc. etc.
  }
module.exports = kafka();
```

So now in:

**userController.js**

```
const kafka = require('.../kafka');
router.get('/user', (req,res) => {
  kafka.then(k => {
    k.publish(req.user, 'userTopic'); // or whatever. This is just an example.
  });
})
```

In this way, in the event an user makes a request during bootstrap, the request will still be handled (but will take some time). Requests made when the promise is already resolved won't notice anything.

- There's no such thing as multiple threads in node. Anything you declare in a commonJS module or you write to `process` will be available in every request.

2-

> How do I properly handle exceptions in a Node.js server process? If a PHP server script throws a fatal exception only that specific request dies, all other requests and any new ones run fine. If a fatal error happens in a Node.js server, it sounds like it would kill the entire process and thus all requests with it.

This really depends in the kind of exception that you find. It is specifically related to the request being processed, or is something critical for the whole application?

In the former case, you want to catch the exception and don't allow the whole thread to die. **Now, 'catch the exception' in javascript is tricky**, because you cannot `catch` asynchronous exceptions/errors, and you would likely use `process.on('unhandledRejection')` to handle that, like:

// main.js

```
try {
  bootstrapMongoDb();
  bootstrapKafka();
  bootstrapSecrets();
  ... wahtever
  bootstrapExpress();
} catch(e){
   // read what `e` brings and decide.
   // however, is worth to mention that errors raised during handling
   // http request won't ever get handled here, because they are
   // asynchronous. try/catch in javascript don't catch asynchronous errors.
 }

process.on('unhandledRejection', e => {
  // now here we are treating unhandled promise rejections, and errors that raise
  // in express controllers are likely end up here. of course, I'm talking about
  // promise rejections. I am not sure if this can catch Errors thrown in callbacks.
 // You should never `throw new Error` inside an asynchronous callback. 

});
```

Handling errors in node application is a whole topic on its own, too broad to be considered here. However some tips shouldn't do harm:

- Never throw errors in callbacks. `throw` is synchronous. Callbacks and asynchrony should rely on an `error` parameter or a promise rejection.
- You better get used to promises. Promises really improve error management in asynchronous code.
- Javascript errors can be decorated with extra fields, so you can fill in trace id's and other id's that may be useful when reading logs of your system, given you will log your unhandled errors.

Now, in the latter case... sometimes there are failures that are totally disastrous for your app. Maybe you totally need a connection to a kafka or a mongo server, and if it is broken, then you may want to kill your application so clients receive a 503 when trying to connect.

Then, in some scenarios, you may want to kill your app, then let another service to reboot it when database is available again. This depends a lot on infrastructure and you may as well not kill your app never.

If you don't have a infrastructure that handles the health and reboot of your web service for you, it is probably safer to never let your application die. Said so, it's a good thing to at least use tools like nodemon or PM2 to ensure your app will relaunch after going down.

### Bonus: why you should not throw errors in callbacks

Thrown errors propagates through the callstack. You have, let's say, function A who calls B, who in turn then calls C. Then C throw an Error. All of them only have synchronous code.

In such scenario, error propagates to B and, if it don't `catch` it, it propagates to A, and so on.

Now let's say that, instead, C doesn't throw an error by itself, but do call `fs.readFile(path, callback)`. In the callback function, an error is thrown.

Here, when the callback is invoked, and the error thrown, A is already done and left the stack long ago, hundreds of milliseconds ago, maybe even more.

This means that any `catch` block in A **won't catch the error, because is not even there already**:

```
function bootstrapTimeout() {

try {
  setTimeout(() => {
    throw new Error('foo');
    console.log('paco');
    }, 200);

} catch (e) {
 console.log('error trapped!');
} 

}

function bootstrapInterval() {

  setInterval(() => {
  console.log('interval')
  }, 50);
}

console.log('start');
bootstrapTimeout();
bootstrapInterval();
```

If you run that snippet, you would see how the error reach the top level and kill the process, even if the `throw new Error('foo');` line was placed within a try/catch block.

#### error, result interface

Instead of using Errors to handle exceptions in asynchronous code, node.js has the standard behavior of expose an `(error, result)` interface for every callback you pass to an asynchronous method. If, for instance, `fs.readFile` happens to go wrong because the filename did not exist, it does not throw an error, it invokes the callback with the corresponding Error as the `error` parameter.

Like:

```
fs.readFile('notexists.png', (error, callback) => {

  if(error){
    // foo
  }
  else {
    http.post('http://something.com', result, (error, callback) => {
      if(error){
        // oops, something went wrong with an http request
      } else {
        // keep working
        // etc.
        // maybe more callbacks, always with the dreadful 'if (error)'...
      }
    })
  }
});
```

You always control errors in async operations in the callback, you should never throw.

Now this is a pain in the ass. Promises allow for much better error control **because you can control async errors in one single catch block**:

```
fsReadFilePromise('something.png')
.then(res => someHttpRequestPromise(res))
.then(httpResponse => someOtherAsyncMethod(httpResponse))
.then(_ => maybeSomeLoggingOrWhatever() )
.catch(e => {
  // here you can control any error thrown in the previous chain.
});
```

And there's also async/await that allow you to mix async and sync code and treat promise rejections in catch blocks:

```
await function main() {
  try {
    a(); // some sync code
    await b(); // some promise
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e); // either an error throw in a() or a promise rejection reason in b();
  }
}
```

However keep in mind that `await` is no magic and you really need to understand promises and asynchrony well in order to use it properly.

At the end, you always end up with one error control flow for synchronous errors via `try/catch`, and another for asynchronous errors, via callback parameters or promise rejections.

Callbacks **can** use `try/catch` when consuming synchronous api's, but should never `throw`.  Any function can use `catch` to handle synchronous errors, but cannot rely on `catch` blocks to handle asynchronous errors. Kinda messy.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you elaborate on "never throw errors in callbacks"? I know Promises and async functions, but I wasn't aware I wasn't supposed to throw errors inside of them. How would I throw an exception in a promise that I'm "await"ing somewhere?

Comment: I add another section to the answer @Fabis

Answer (score 1):

> Does it make sense to pre-load some data during Express.js startup (like reading private keys from file) so that it is already in memory when needed by a request and it would get re-used each time without being re-read from file?

Yes it make sense if you structure your code to let these data be available in the request handler. In the following example, based on what i know, the `staticResponse` is readed only one time.

```
const express = require('express');
const staticResponse = fs.readFileSync('./data');
const app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.json(staticResponse);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

> How do I properly handle exceptions in a Node.js server process? If a fatal error happens in a Node.js server, it sounds like it would kill the entire process and thus all requests with it.

Exactly, an unhandled exception make the entire nodejs process crash. There are multiple ways to manage error, there isn't 'the one for all' solution. Depends on how you write you're code.

`all requests with it` => keep in mind that nodejs is single thread.

```
app.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        const data = JSON.parse(req.body.stringedData);

        // use data

        res.sendStatus(200);

    } catch (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
});
```